# How do outliers affect the k-means algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, outliers, k-means

I searched the internet to find out about the effects of outliers on k-means clustering, but could not find any useful source. Does it cause bad clusters to be formed? If so, how?

(Please also provide a simple example with data such as a list of integers so that my doubt can be clarified.)

Comment: The answer likely hinges on what you really mean by "outlier" and "bad cluster." Ordinarily an "outlier" is just that--a data value that according to some measure is "far" from typical data values.  In itself it's neither "good" nor "bad"--it just is.  One might suppose that a sufficiently extreme outlier or group of outliers ought to be in its own cluster, so are you asking whether common K-means algorithms will tend to produce that kind of solution?

Comment: I think the question is too broad, please narrow it.